# TimesTen Dialect Hibernate 3

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, timesten

I am trying to use hibernate with a TimesTen database.

I have the correct dialect: TimesTenDialect1122.java but I am unsure of how to add this to my project within Eclipse.

The package in the file is declared as:

```
package org.hibernate.dialect;
```

So how do I add it to my project correctly.

I currently have it in my resources folder and within my hibernate config flie I have

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" >
org.hibernate.dialect.TimesTenDialect1122 
</property>
```

But this obviously does not work as it can't find the class.

Stack trace and error:

```
INFO: JDBC isolation level: READ_COMMITTED
Dec 17, 2014 10:38:41 AM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider     configure
INFO: using driver: com.timesten.jdbc.TimesTenDriver at URL:   jdbc:timesten:client:dsn=DEV TT
Dec 17, 2014 10:38:41 AM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: connection properties: {user=USER, password=PASSWORD}
Dec 17, 2014 10:38:41 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: RDBMS: TimesTen, version: 11.02.02.0007 Oracle TimesTen IMDB version 11.2.2.7.8
Dec 17, 2014 10:38:41 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JDBC driver: JDBC-ODBC Bridge (ttclient1122.dll), version: 11.2.2.7.4   (11.02.0002.0007)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found:     org.hibernate.dialect.TimesTenDialect1122
at org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:81)
at org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:42)
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.determineDialect(SettingsFactory.java:426)
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:128)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2073)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1298)
at com.fil.foras.ActAsPOC.ActAsPOC.main(ActAsPOC.java:17)
```

Comment: Do you have a persistence.xml file?

Comment: @Simon Nicholls add exception error stack trace

Comment: I don't no - is that JPA specific - I should point out I'm a complete beginner with Hibernate!

Comment: After a little reading - I'm using the hibernate native APIs - I will look into JPA although I think I'll run into the same problem surely as I will still need this dialect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Oracle TimesTen documentation](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/timesten/1122/quickstart/html/developer/orm/howto_orm.html):

> Note that this configuration uses the included Hibernate dialect
>   called TimesTenDialect1122. This dialect is not included in current
>   versions of the Hibernate distribution. The TimesTenDialect1122 class
>   is compiled and packaged into this application. This is the
>   recommended Hibernate dialect for TimesTen 11.2.2 applications.

So you probably didn't include the jar containing the dialect into your project class-path:

> Make sure property timesten.jdbc.driver.jar and the home.dir of the
>   ORM installation are set correctly in file build.properties

Comment: I already have the JDBC driver in my project but I've found a readme that says you need to build the dialect class with ant which will solve all my needs - this pointed me in the right direction though thank you!